# A dataGrid column depending on another column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I'm working on WPF - MVVM Application.

I have to add products in a blank `InvoicedataGrid`.

Each product has a reference number `refsup` and a `description`.

When I add a row in the `InvoicedataGrid`, I choose the reference number in a `ComboboxColumn` and the description appear in the next column.

How can I do that? *trying to keep the MVVM pattern*

## **View**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInvoice"
          Margin="5"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          AddingNewItem="dataGridInvoice_AddingNewItem">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SuppNb"
                            Binding="{Binding suppInvNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier"
                            Binding="{Binding supplier, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="*" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ref Supplier"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Products, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource supplier}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="refsup"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding refSupp}"
                                SelectedValuePath="refsup"
                                Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                            Binding="{Binding description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

## **ViewModel**

```
public class InvoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Context ctx = new Context();
    public InvoiceViewModel()
    {
        Get(false);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Invoice> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<Invoice> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return collection;
        }
        set
        {
            collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }

    private Invoice _selected;
    public Invoice Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

    private void Get(bool loadDataFirst)
    {
        if (loadDataFirst) ctx.Invoices.Load();
        Collection = ctx.Invoices.Local;
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void Delete()
    {
        var id = Selected;
        var invoice = (from i in ctx.Invoices
                    where i.idInvoice == id.idInvoice
                    select i).SingleOrDefault();
        Collection.Remove(invoice);
    }

    private Invoice _currentItem;
    public Invoice CurrentItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }

    #region "Command"

    private ICommand saveCommand;
    private ICommand removeCommand;

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return saveCommand ?? (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Save(), p => this.CanSave()));
        }
    }

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return removeCommand ?? (removeCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Delete(), p => this.CanDelete()));
        }
    }

    public bool CanDelete()
    {
        if (Selected != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## **Model**

```
public partial class product
{
    public int idproduct { get; set; }
    public string @ref { get; set; }
    public int supplier { get; set; }
    public string refsup { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int MOQ { get; set; }
    public int unit { get; set; }
    public decimal priceMOQ { get; set; }

    public virtual foodSupplier foodSupplier { get; set; }
    public virtual unit unit1 { get; set; }
}
public partial class Invoice : ViewModelBase
{
    public int idInvoice { get; set; }
    public string suppInvNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> supplier { get; set; }
    public string refSupp { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }    

    public virtual foodSupplier foodSupplier { get; set; }
    public virtual shop shop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` which defines the `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`. The visibility of control defined in DataTemplate of CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate can be toggled based on the value chosen.

However, `DataGridTemplateColumnor` any other supported dataGrid columns doesn't lie in Visual tree of DataGrid, hence by default it doesn't inherit DataContext of DataGrid. Since, they doesn't lie in same VisualTree so any try to get DataContext using RelativeSource won't work as well because DataGrid won't able to traverse up to DataGrid.

So, there are various ways to achieve that though; out of which I would be demonstrating one below:

1. Create a `FrameworkElement` will inherit the DataContext even when they’re not in the visual or logical tree. So, we can take advantage of that to our use.
2. Create a `ContentControl` which binds to ProxyElement
3. Create a Convertor which will toggle the visibility of control (Defined in CellTemplate or CellEditingTemplate).
4. The created proxy element can be bind to Visibility DB.

   ```
   <Grid>
      <Grid.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"></FrameworkElement>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"></ContentControl>
      <DataGrid>
          <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                               <TextBox Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Path=DataContext.refsub, Converter={StaticResource ConvertorToConvertrefsubToVisibility}}" />
                           </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>               
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
           </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
   </Grid>
   ```